# Can't get current location of last known location for my app

Tags: java

i have an app that can't receive any location. I have to wait for a day in order it get current or last known location. Please help

This app are just like carousell buy and sell app that need log & lat to get location

Below are my code. I'm not good at programming. Still learning. Thanks

```
// MARK: - GET CURRENT LOCATION ------------------------------------------------------
protected void getCurrentLocation() {
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_LOW);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    assert locationManager != null;
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (currentLocation != null) {
        getCityCountryNames();

        // Try to find your current Location one more time
    } else {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0, this);
    }
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (PermissionsUtils.hasPermissions(this, locationPermissions)) {
        return;
    }

    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    currentLocation = location;

    if (currentLocation != null) {
        getCityCountryNames();
        // NO GPS location found!
    } else {
        Configs.simpleAlert(getString(R.string.get_location_failure), AdsListActivity.this);

        // Set New York City as default currentLocation
        currentLocation = new Location("provider");
        currentLocation.setLatitude(Configs.DEFAULT_LOCATION.latitude);
        currentLocation.setLongitude(Configs.DEFAULT_LOCATION.longitude);

        // Set distance and city labels
        String distFormatted = String.format("%.0f", distanceInMiles);
        distanceTxt.setText(getString(R.string.ads_list_distance_formatted, distFormatted));
        cityCountryTV.setText(getString(R.string.not_available_text_placeholder));

        // Call query
        queryAds();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't receive location"? Are there any errors?

Comment: This app suppose to displaying app with my current location. But it's not working. Just blank. Refer screenshot here https://i.imgur.com/Nozdmxu.jpg

Comment: But you only update your views if `currentLocation == null`, since that's what `onLocationChanged` reads. And since you also assign the current location in there, it's only going to be `null` once. I'm not sure what the default location is, or what `ads_list_distance_formatted` is, but that part is definitely not looking right. And you also stop updates of location manager after receiving first time, so-o-o...

Comment: Here are the code:

String distFormatted = String.format("%.0f", distanceInMiles);
            distanceTxt.setText(getString(R.string.ads_list_distance_formatted, distFormatted));

Comment: Just noticed: on the very first line of `onLocationChanged`, you say you don't want to do anything if your app is given location permissions. Must be why the app is not doing anything.